# Converting responses returned from REST API into CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to write response returned from REST API into a csv file. As there are multiple requests, I am calling API on the requests one by one. So, there would be multiple responses. I am not able to achieve desired format.

***Desired format :***

```
name,job,id,createdAt
morpheus,leader,727,2018-10-12T12:04:39.234Z
Mark,SSE,925,2018-10-12T12:04:40.200Z
Taylor,SE,247,2018-10-12T12:04:41.115Z
```

***Code :***

```
import requests

url ='https://reqres.in/api/users'
data =[{
    "name": "morpheus",
    "job": "leader"
},
    {"name":"Mark",
    "job":"SSE"},

    {"name":"Taylor",
    "job":"SE"}
]

with open('response.csv','w') as f:
    for element in data:
        r=requests.post(url,json=element)
        response = json.loads(r.text)
        for key in response.keys():
            #f.write("%s,%s"%(key,response[key]))
```

Comment: You're writing csv: First write out the headings for the response, once, then write out the data without headings.

Comment: If you're okay importing external packages, pandas has a nice [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) constructor which will create a table from json records, then a nice [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method to write out a csv file. If your json data is strictly formatted every time this will require two lines of code to write.

Answer (score 0):

Python brings builtin support for csv reading and writing that allows you to define dialects with different separators and escaping logic.

Cell values containing the separator or newline or your escape chars need to be escaped or the resulting csv is broken - the csv module does that for you. You can choose between different formats (excel can be picky when loading csv), or define your own.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the data you are getting from the server has the exact keys you're looking for, something like this should work:

```
data = [] # Your data here.
url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users'

desired_columns = ['name', 'job', 'id', 'createdAt']
with open('response.csv', 'w') as f:

    # First we need to write the column names to the file
    f.write(','.join(desired_columns) + '\n')

    for element in data:
        r = requests.post(url, json=element)

        response = json.loads(r.text)

        # Here, I will assume response has 'name', 'job', 'id' and 'createdAt'
        # as keys to the dictionary. We will save them to the list 'data_to_write'
        # And then write that out the same way we did above.
        data_to_write = []
        for column in desired_columns:
            data_to_write.append(response[column])

        f.write(','.join(data_to_write) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added +"\n" to split lines in header and records.

Comment: what about escaping if the values contain your chosen separator? this will break your csv. use the builtin python csv writer.